# Tab key not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my code for validating numeric values only, which works.

But I get an alert message when I press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

```
$j('#ctl00_cphMain_txtQuantity').keypress(function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $j(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && (event.which !=8)  ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please Enter Valid Quantity");
    }
```

Comment: well the tab key is `9` in the keyCode || which..so...

Comment: Using regex would be easier in my opinion. Can I show you that solution rather?

Comment: Denying the user to use the tab key is usually a sign of bad interface design. You should also generally consider not displaying a modal dialog when the user presses a wrong button. And in a web page context, just checking for key presses won't reliably forbid invalid characters. (Consider copy and paste). It's better to A) use a regexp to check for valid input as the other suggested, and B) just highlight the invalid input field and display an error message per DOM. Check out the jQuery validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use `regex` instead of keycodes, as there is an arbitrary number of keycodes you'll need to account for. What about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>? Or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>?

Try this:

```
$("#foo").keyup(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var regex = /^\d+$/;

    if (!regex.test($input.val())) {
        alert("Please enter numeric values only");
        $input.val($input.val().replace(/\D/, ''));
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tnjBj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you add an event.keyCode!=9 in the if clause it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown instead of keypress instead of keydown.

Sample:

```
        $('#test').keydown(function (event) {
            if (((event.which != 46) ||
                 ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1))
                && ((event.which < 48)
                    || (event.which > 57))
                && (event.which != 8)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("Please Enter Valid Quantity");
            }
        });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your code at these places:

```
$j('#ctl00_cphMain_txtQuantity').keypress(function (event) {
if ((event.which != 46 ||  
    $j(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && 
    (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && 
    (event.which !=8)  ) {
//              ---^----------------------------9 is the tabkey     
        event.preventDefault(); // <------------remove this
        alert("Please Enter Valid Quantity");
}
```

i have done something in this fiddle which gets alerts when other keypress event happens but not the tab key: http://jsfiddle.net/8YNFw/

you can find the keycodes here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: you can accept it as answer if this helped you. just check the big arrow.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with regex in FireFox. It may not work with tab key test. I used following code and got worked on all browsers

```
jQuery(document).on( "keypress", ".element1, .element2", function(e) {
        var regExp = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z \b]*$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

        if (e.keyCode != 9) { // For FireFox
            if (!regExp.test(key)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
```